# pip raise FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-install-_2yekith/pyqt5/setup.py'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pip, pyqt5

I tried to install [pyqt5](/questions/tagged/pyqt5) but I got:

**Exception:**

```py
Collecting pyqt5
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/fb/eb51731f2dc7c22d8e1a63ba88fb702727b324c6352183a32f27f73b8116/PyQt5-5.14.1.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tokenize.py", line 447, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-install-_2yekith/pyqt5/setup.py'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-_2yekith/pyqt5/
```

**Python Version:**

> Python 3.7.3

**pip Version:**

> pip 18.1 from /home/user/pyqt-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7

**Question:**

What is the problem and How can I solve this problem?

Comment: try install `pip install PyQt5==5.14`

Comment: Seems like a popular problem with PyQT5 5.14.1: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59771194/7976758. Perhaps a bug in PyQT5.