# pip3 installation commands repeated failure to create file '/tmp/pip-install-xxxxx/package'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyqt5, setup.py

Whenever I try to install a package, for example `pip3 install PyQt5` the command fails with a message about a missing directory in the `/tmp` directory

```
pip3 install PyQt5
Collecting PyQt5
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/fb/eb51731f2dc7c22d8e1a63ba88fb702727b324c6352183a32f27f73b8116/PyQt5-5.14.1.tar.gz (3.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 3.2MB 19.3MB/s 
  Installing build dependencies ... done
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tokenize.py", line 447, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-install-0shdy0kn/PyQt5/setup.py'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-0shdy0kn/PyQt5/
```

When I look in the `/tmp` directory no `pip-install-xxxxxxx` directories exist and it looks like the process doesn't create them at all.

Comment: Seems like a popular problem with PyQT5 5.14.1: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59768179/7976758. Perhaps a bug in PyQT5.

Comment: execute: `pip3 install pyqt5==5.14`

Answer (score 1):

As a quick fix you can `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5`

But for the sake of your question. Does this happen with any package?

Can you try installing any of the following just to see if it works, these are just quick examples.

```
pip3 install numpy==1.18.1
pip3 install pandas==0.25.3
pip3 install pep8==1.7.1
pip3 install pika==1.1.0
```

One reason could be that `PyQt5` is to be used with `python 2` and hence might only work with `pip install PyQt5`