# I Tried to Install PyQtWebEngine, Always Stuck on the Same Problem. Couldn't Fine the solution anywhere

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pip, pyqt5, webengine

I'm new to this. Sorry for the mess.

I've been trying to install PyQtWebEngin, first On zorin os which is dualboot along with Windows10, it failed. Then I decided to install it on Linux Mint on VM inside Windows10. The error result is alway the same.

Here take a look,

```
poo@poo:~/Downloads$ pip3 install PyQtWebEngine
Collecting PyQtWebEngine
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/71/be/cd5243a456aae37788eebd8333d2326fd830de7ce1f1ac6618e966a66862/PyQtWebEngine-5.14.0-5.14.0-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.7 (from PyQtWebEngine)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/69/d2/92d85b0865fe68755488a30eec1c2b1b14da6c96c74441dc1c88e0659397/PyQt5_sip-12.7.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting PyQt5>=5.14 (from PyQtWebEngine)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/fb/eb51731f2dc7c22d8e1a63ba88fb702727b324c6352183a32f27f73b8116/PyQt5-5.14.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tokenize.py", line 452, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-build-3tqr21z4/PyQt5/setup.py'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-3tqr21z4/PyQt5/
```

Can you guys help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: execute: `pip3 install --upgrade pip &&  pip3 install PyQtWebEngine`

Answer (score 1):

Your `pip` seems to be trying to use a source distribution of `PyQt5` for installation, but it seems that `setup.py` is missing from the `.tar.gz` on pypi, which is odd.

According to the [docs](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html#building-and-installing-from-source) installing from source is not recommended anyway

> However using pip to install from the source package is not recommended

I do not know why your pip chose to download the `.tar.gz` in the first place. Looking at the other `whl` files from you log with `cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`, there is a `PyQt5-5.14.1-5.14.0-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl` on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/#files) that should be compatible with your system and should be the first choice of `pip` for downloading.

You can try to do it manually:

```
wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ea/9d/d609aab4111d9d74857fb73067f7de4ca38fc1f7fff87ceba092681754cf/PyQt5-5.14.1-5.14.0-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
pip install PyQt5-5.14.1-5.14.0-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
```

And then try your installation again

Comment: "*it seems that setup.py is missing from the .tar.gz on pypi, which is odd*" Odd, but true. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/59768179/7976758 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/59771194/7976758

Comment: @phd thank you for linking to the other questions. Any idea why `pip` might have chosen to download the source release instead of the `whl` file?

Comment: 32-bit Python? `pip` not supporting `manylinux2014`?

Comment: @FlyingTeller I tried your solution, it turned out that pyqt5    whl isn't supported. This is the result

`poo@poo:~$ pip3 install PyQt5-5.14.1-5.14.0-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
PyQt5-5.14.1-5.14.0-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

also I'm trying to look up on links given by @phd, successfully install the `pyqt5`. and now I'm facing an issue that `pip3` still refer to the old `.tar.gz` cache. I'm going to figure it out and I'll give  some updates.
thank you guys.